# Calculate only distinct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table and i want output as given below
want only distinct values.
I used cross apply but doesn't work.

```
Customer    Book
C1               B1
C2               B1
C3               B1
```

I need output: All combination of all customers. Only distinct values

Example:

```
Customers
C1,C2
C1,C3
C2,C3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, at least for your sample data and the narrative:

```
select distinct case when t1.customer > t2.customer then t2.customer + ',' + t1.customer else t1.customer + ',' + t2.customer end
from tbl t1 
join tbl t2
on t1.book = t2.book
and t1.customer <> t2.customer
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Primary key column

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB( ID INT IDENTITY,Customer VARCHAR(10),   Book VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #TAB
SELECT 'C1','B1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C2','B1'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C3','B1'


SELECT T2.Customer ,T.Customer
FROM #TAB T
INNER JOIN #TAB T2 ON T.ID >T2.ID
```

Result :

```
+----------+----------+
| Customer | Customer |
+----------+----------+
| C1       | C2       |
| C1       | C3       |
| C2       | C3       |
+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want customers with the same book, query should be something similar. Note the < operator, since we want (C1, C2), not (C2, C1):

```
select distinct a.customer_col , b.customer_col
from customer_table a join  customer_table b
on a.book_col = b.book_col and a.customer_col < b.customer_col
```

Answer (score 0):

Hoping i understood question correctly,

Please check below query. Please replace table and columns with your original one.

Rextester link - http://rextester.com/RPPXQO21553

```
select
a.customer_col , b.customer_col , a.rn , b.rn 
from
(select customer_col , row_number() over (order by customer_col) rn from  customer_table) a join 
(select customer_col , row_number() over (order by customer_col) rn from  customer_table) b
on a.customer_col <> b.customer_col
and a.rn < b.rn
order by 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using self join (hope you want customers with the same book), Sample script below

```
select  t1.customer,t2.customer
from    @tble t1
    inner join  @tble t2 on t1.book = t2.book
                            and t1.customer < t2.customer
```

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer as

```
select B,A from(select a.customer A,b.customer B, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by a.customer)rn from CustomerData a
JOIN CustomerData b ON a.customer>b.customer )x
```